# Error at line 2/16: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Tags: oracle

```sql
CREATE TABLE Actor (
  actor_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  actor_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  actor_gender ENUM('M', 'F', 'Other') NOT NULL,
  actor_birthdate DATE NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Director (
  director_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  director_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  director_birthdate DATE NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Movie (
  movie_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  movie_title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  movie_release_date DATE NOT NULL,
  movie_runtime INT NOT NULL,
  movie_rating DECIMAL(3,1) NOT NULL,
  genre_id INT NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (genre_id) REFERENCES Genre(genre_id)
);

CREATE TABLE Genre (
  genre_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  genre_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE MovieCast (
  movie_id INT NOT NULL,
  actor_id INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (movie_id, actor_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (movie_id) REFERENCES Movie(movie_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (actor_id) REFERENCES Actor(actor_id)
);

CREATE TABLE DirectorOf (
  movie_id INT NOT NULL,
  director_id INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (movie_id, director_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (movie_id) REFERENCES Movie(movie_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (director_id) REFERENCES Director(director_id)
);
```

I dont know where is the error

Comment: ORA is an Oracle error, not MySQL, yet this looks like code in the MySQL dialect.

Comment: What is on line 2, character 16?

Comment: Create the table `Genre` before `Movie`, because the foreign key in `Movie` needs that the `Genre` table exist first. Other than that, I tested these statements on MySQL 8.0.32 and they work fine. I don't know why you describe an Oracle error in the subject, because this is not Oracle's flavor of SQL.

Comment: Are you inadvertently using the MySQL dialect on what's actually an Oracle DB server?

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle , neither `AUTO_INCREMENT` nor `ENUM` is valid syntax. You want:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Actor (
  actor_id        INT
                  GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
                  PRIMARY KEY,
  actor_name      VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  actor_gender    VARCHAR2(5)
                  CHECK ( actor_gender IN ('M', 'F', 'Other'))
                  NOT NULL,
  actor_birthdate DATE NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Director (
  director_id        INT
                     GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
                     PRIMARY KEY,
  director_name      VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  director_birthdate DATE NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Genre (
  genre_id   INT
             GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
             PRIMARY KEY,
  genre_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Movie (
  movie_id           INT
                     GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
                     PRIMARY KEY,
  movie_title        VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  movie_release_date DATE NOT NULL,
  movie_runtime      INT NOT NULL,
  movie_rating       DECIMAL(3,1) NOT NULL,
  genre_id           REFERENCES Genre(genre_id)
                     NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE MovieCast (
  movie_id REFERENCES Movie(movie_id),
  actor_id REFERENCES Actor(actor_id),
  PRIMARY KEY (movie_id, actor_id)
);

CREATE TABLE DirectorOf (
  movie_id    REFERENCES Movie(movie_id),
  director_id REFERENCES Director(director_id),
  PRIMARY KEY (movie_id, director_id)
);
```

*Note: When you declare a foreign key constraint you do not need to declare the data type and it will be inherited from the table/column being referenced.*

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/O6ooONuk)